# where do I put insert db query codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my controller I have the following functions that upload an image to a local directory which works fine. I now want to store in the db. I just need to figure out where to put the code I already have and think is correct.

I need to insert this:

```
  $this->location->store_file_path($file);
```

into either before or after the pic is uploaded in local directory. Where should it go?

Controller:

```
public function image() {

    //type must either be type=logo or type=profile_picture

    if (isset($_FILES['file']) && isset($_POST['type'])) {

        //Codeigniter upload
        $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $config['max_size'] = 5120;
        $config['max_width'] = '1024';
        $config['max_height'] = '768';
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {

            $status = 'error';
            $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
        } else {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
             //$file_id = $this->files_model->insert_file($data['file_name'], $_POST['title']);
            if ($data) {
                $status = "success";
                $data['url'] = $config['upload_path'] . $data['file_name'];
                $msg = $data;
            } else {
                unlink($data['full_path']);
                $status = "error";
                $msg = "Something went wrong when saving the file, please try again.";
            }


        }
    } else {
        $status = "error";
        $msg = "Please select a file to upload";
    }
    echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
}
```

Here is my model function:

```
public function store_file_path($file)
{

    $this->db->insert('TACTIFY_locationcards', 'name'=>$file);
}
```

Comment: just edited and updated parameter passed.

Comment: just insert it normally like you would do using active record, there is nothing special in your case

Comment: Just a personal tip, while it's your application, and you can place your code where you want (you don't event need to use models), it's probably better to place your upload code in the model as well, maybe as another method. This is because if you decide you want to have another upload method for the same purpose, you'll need to duplicate the upload code in the controller. Placing it, and calling the same code from the model would reduce the duplication.

Comment: thank you. that is true. However, this is not my app and I have to deal with spaghetti code everywhere.

Comment: I inserted and tested but for some odd reason it breaks my crop function which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the following line in controler

```
$status = "success";
 + $file = $config['upload_path'] . $data['file_name'];
 + $this->location->store_file_path($file);
 $msg = $file;
```

change the model

```
public function store_file_path($file)
{
   + $this->db->set('name', $file); 
   + $this->db->insert('TACTIFY_locationcards'); 
   - $this->db->insert('TACTIFY_locationcards', 'name'=>$file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you only write to a database once all verification has been done and the data has been written to the file.

If I read your code correctly success is at the point:

```
           if ($data) {
            $status = "success";
            $data['url'] = $config['upload_path'] . $data['file_name'];
            $msg = $data;
```

I would put the line here:

```
           if ($data) {
            $status = "success";
            $data['url'] = $config['upload_path'] . $data['file_name'];
            $msg = $data;
            $this->location->store_file_path($file);
```